# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, xml, java-8, certificado-ssl, soapui

Estoy tratando llamar desde mi aplicación Java a un Webservice de Soap de la siguiente manera:

```
@Override
    public String getListaTiposMensajes(String idSesion) throws Exception {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        String pendientes = "";
        
        try{
                        
            String wsdlURL = "https://xxx.xxxx.es/services/ws/ObtenerPendientesGeneral?wsdl";
            String namespace = "https://obtenerpendientesgeneral.servicio.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx";
            String serviceName ="ObtenerPendientesGeneral";
            QName serviceQN = new QName(namespace, serviceName);
            
            ObtenerPendientesGeneralService service = (ObtenerPendientesGeneralService) ObtenerPendientesGeneralService.create(new URL(wsdlURL), serviceQN);
            ObtenerPendientesGeneralPortType port = service.getPort(ObtenerPendientesGeneralPortType.class);
            
            pendientes = port.obtenerPendientesGeneral(idSesion);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception. Problemas en la llamada al servicio ObtenerPendientesGeneral, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pendientes;
    }
```

Donde **ObtenerPendientesGeneralService** es una clase de tipo *@WebServiceCliente* y **ObtenerPendientesGeneralPortType** es de *@WebService*

En *ObtenerPendientesGeneralService service* ocurre lo siguiente:

> [11/12/23 9:51:09:577 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R
> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: The following WSDL exception
> occurred: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : :
> javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : :
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect [11/12/23
> 9:51:09:578 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:578 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:578 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1202)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:578 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:249)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:578 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:172)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:578 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:143)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:578 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:579 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:78)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:579 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.(ServiceDelegate.java:218)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:579 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:83)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:579 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:79)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:579 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:92) [11/12/23 9:51:09:579
> CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:722) [11/12/23 9:51:09:579
> CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> es.seguridadsocial.palexws.descargarmensajes.ObtenerPendientesGeneralImpl.getListaTiposMensajes(ObtenerPendientesGeneralImpl.java:31)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:579 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> es.seguridadsocial.palexws.service.DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.obtenerPendientesGeneral(DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.java:38)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:579 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> es.seguridadsocial.palexws.service.DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.ejecutar(DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.java:15)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:579 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> es.seguridadsocial.palexws.ws.PALEXWSSoapBindingImpl.descargaMensajesEntidades(PALEXWSSoapBindingImpl.java:12)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:580 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [11/12/23
> 9:51:09:580 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:580 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:580 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) [11/12/23 9:51:09:580
> CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.invokeTargetOperation(JavaDispatcher.java:120)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:580 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:118)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:580 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:111)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:580 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:581 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:212)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:581 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:581 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1633)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:581 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [11/12/23
> 9:51:09:581 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [11/12/23
> 9:51:09:581 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:581 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:581 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1134)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4238)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2210)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1033)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:582 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [11/12/23
> 9:51:09:583 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:584 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:584 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [11/12/23
> 9:51:09:584 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909) [11/12/23
> 9:51:09:584 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R Caused by:
> javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : :
> javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : :
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect [11/12/23
> 9:51:09:584 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R     at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:234)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:584 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.(WSDL4JWrapper.java:156)
> [11/12/23 9:51:09:584 CET] 000000d5 SystemErr     R   at
> org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1182)

En la herramienta Soap accedo sin problemas, pero en Java no. La URL de acceso pertenece a un Ministerio el cual contiene un certificado con firma con sus dos ficheros: uno publico de extensión .cer y uno privado de extensión .p12 y su contraseña para acceder.

Me gustaría saber cómo utilizar el certificado en Java para poder acceder a la URL y que me devuelva datos. También me gustaría saber si el timeout que me devuelve tiene que ver con Proxy.

Uso como servidor local Websphere v9

Estos son los parametros de entrada en SOAP:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:obt="https://xxxxx.sxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
            <obt:ObtenerPendientesGeneralIn>
                <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
                        <ns2:mensajeWS xmlns:ns2="https://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet/3.27">
                            <solicitudGetPendientesType>
                                <idSesion>1234</idSesion>
                                <idAplicacion>idAplicacion</idAplicacion>
                                <idSujetoExterno>11111111111</idSujetoExterno>
                            </solicitudGetPendientesType>
                        </ns2:mensajeWS>]]>
            </obt:ObtenerPendientesGeneralIn>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Cuando accedo a la url de un navegador (en este caso Chrome) me pide un certificado tal y como pone en el pantallazo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo la versión 8 de Java, no tengo permiso para utilizar una versión superior.

Si necesitáis más información no dudéis en pedírmelo.

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.